# JavaScript create dynamically HTML section

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to create programmatically the following HTML section in a specific div, by inserting the Dropdown name and Drop Item.  Thank you for any help.

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="button-dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown 1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Drop Item 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In simple, I would like to create 1 or 2 methods which accepts 2 strings, 1 for the Dropdown and the other for the Drop Item

Comment: `$('yourHtmlStringHere').appendTo('#targetElement')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var str='<ul class="nav"><li class="button-dropdown">';
          str+=  '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown 1</a>';
             str+= '<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">Drop Item 1</a></li></ul></li></ul>';

$('#div-id').html(str);
```

`div-id` is your specific div ID .

Answer (score 1):

as @Nihar Sarkar pointed but with the function with the two strings

```
function updateList(Dropdown1,DropItem1List){

    var ListOfItems = '';

    for(var i=0; i<DropItem1List.length;i++){
        ListOfItems +=  '<li><a href="#">'+DropItem1List[i]+'</a></li>';
    }

    var htmlCode = '<ul class="nav">'
            +'<li class="button-dropdown">'
                +'<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">'+Dropdown1+'</a>'
                +'<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                    +ListOfItems
            +'</ul>'
        +'</li>'
    +'</ul>';

    $('#yourDivId').html(htmlCode);

}
```

or if the html already exists in your page

```
$('#yourDivId .nav .button-dropdown a.dropdown-toggle').text(Dropdown1);
$('#yourDivId .nav .button-dropdown ul.dropdown-menu').text(DropItem1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  What if I would like to append, for example if I keep press the new will be added? Also, there is a way to add multiple DropItem, fr example in a loop?

Comment: try the new version of code to add multiple DropItem haven't tested but it should work

Comment: $('#yourDivId .nav .button-dropdown ul.dropdown-menu').append('<li><a href="#">'+Item+'</a></li>'); to add one single item to the list

Comment: It works but I can only see only the Dropdown1, DropItem1List is not visible.

Comment: DropItem1List will be a array of strings you want as options of the list for example var DropItem1List =['option1','option2','option3'];

Comment: I passed an array but the elements are not visible.  However, also the first version the item were not visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121056/discussion-between-h-c-and-doro).